# i want to check any checkbox is checked or not in current tr...How its possible?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked, tr

when user click on Allow then deny will be disable or when click on Deny then Allow will be disable.

[image]

this is my table structure..

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Sequence </th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Allow </th>
            <th> Deny </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th class="active">Repositary Service</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="access_tr">
            <td class="sr_no"> 1 </td>
            <td> Select File </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="rights_checkbox" value="select_file/1" name=""> </td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="rights_checkbox" value="select_file/2" name=""> </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use radio button with same name this will do the trick

Comment: yea...i use that trick but their is different different td for the checkbox

Comment: i believe it will still work just make sure that the name of radio button is the same. they will toggle each other

Comment: yea...Thanks  lots i will work.guradio

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $('#yourTalbeId').find('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Checked');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rights_checkbox').on("change", function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(this).closest("tr").find(".rights_checkbox");

    $checkboxes.show();

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $checkboxes.not(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Bit convoluted, but if you really want to do it this way, it'll work.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkezcxh4/1/